# Is there an error in the subspaces test in Chapter 4 of Elementary Linear Algebra 12th edition by Howard Anton?

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I have already studied the book 'Linear Algebra' by Friedberg as an undergraduate student.

In that book, when testing for a subspace, it was sufficient to cheak the inclusion of the zero vector (the additive identity) and closure under the remaining operations(plus and scalar product).

But In Elementary Linear Algebra 12th edition by Howard Anton, it is considered a subspace if one demonstrates closure under operations without necessarily checking for the inclusion of the zero vector.

I think this is wrong.

When I studied abstract algebra using 'A First Course in Abstract Algebra' by Fraleigh, I learned that without an identity element (for addition), the existence of inverses may not be guaranteed.

So, I think If we don't cheak an identity element for addition then doesn't guarantee closure under operations-I mean we can't guarantee existence of inverse for addition-.

So, I think that Howard Anton's subspace test is incorrect because of this.

Am I correct?

If it's not incorrect, could you please explain why it's not incorrect?

Comment: Closedness alone is not sufficient indeed. You have to check at least that your subset is non-empty. Can you please edit your post to include a screenshot of that page of the book?   Such a mistake is hard to believe.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry I cant. Beacuse I'm a korean my book is not enlgish. If I find english book then I will edit this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closedness alone is not sufficient indeed (the empty set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but it is not a subspace). You have to check at least that your subset is non-empty.

Please read your book more carefully: the author includes this non-emptiness condition in his test, and derives (from closedness and non-emptiness) that the subset contains the zero vector: [image]

Comment: Maybe the Korean edition has the error?

Comment: Ah I missed it Thank you. I didn't think of it as being derived from the condition that it is not the empty set. Thank you!